# Domain of $x/(1-e^x)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

This may be a stupid question:
The function $ \frac{x}{1-e^x} $, which positive and negative limits around $0$ are $-1$, is defined or not for $x = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not defined at $x = 0$. However, the function
$$
g(x) = \cases{\frac x{1-e^x} & if $x \neq 0$\\-1 & if $x = 0$}
$$
is mathematically indistinguishable from your function for all non-zero inputs, but it's defined and continuous at $x = 0$ as well.

Comment: I think you want $g(0) = -1$. :)

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer!

Answer (score 0):

it's not defined at zero as you would be dividing by zero

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not defined for $x = 0$, since $e^0 = 1$, so $1 - e^0 = 0$, and division by $0$ is undefined.

On the other hand, there IS a contininuous function $g$ that equals 
your function for every nonzero $x$, and for which $g(0) = -1$.